# maven-dependency-plugin - Failed to execute goal (but executes)

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am newbie in maven and I want maven to copy my final package to certain directory (autodeploy). But I get

```
> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (copy) on
> project xxx: Error copying artifact from bbb to ccc: Failed to copy
> full contents from bbb to ccc -> [Help 1]
```

The strange thing is that maven copies that package but anyway he shows BUILD FAILURE.

My pom:

```
....    
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
         <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
             <silent>true</silent>
             <artifactItems>
                 <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
              </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
          </configuration>
   </execution>
       <execution>
       <id>copy</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
               <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
               <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
               <version>${project.version}</version>
               <type>${project.packaging}</type>
               <outputDirectory>XXX</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
     </execution>                    
  </executions>
```

...
How can it be fixed? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this maven-plugin bug? Please help me because I couldn't find the answer in internet.

EDIT:
Centos 6.4 (64), openjdk 1.7, Netbeans 7.4, Copying over ftp

Comment: File operations as highly OS dependent. Adding the OS you are running on can help.

Comment: This is multi-threading bug in a library used by the maven dependencies plugin. root cause is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-633